# How to get and set task notes with google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet that extract task from my google task api. I can get every field displayed in the task item on the calendar except the note.

What is the code to get and modify the notes. I have tried

```
var resource = {status: "needsAction",completed: null,notes:description,}
var res = Tasks.Tasks.patch(resource, tasklistID, taskid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to get and update the notes of a task.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Get notes

In this sample script, the task IDs and notes of all tasks in a task list are retrieved. When you use this, please set `taskListId`.

```
var taskListId = "### task list ID ###";
var items = Tasks.Tasks.list(taskListId).items;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  Logger.log("taskId: %s, notes: %s", items[i].id, items[i].notes)
}
```

#### Update notes

In this sample script, the notes of a task in a task list is updated. When you use this, please set `taskListId` and `taskId`.

```
var taskListId = "### task list ID ###";
var taskId = "### task ID ###";
var resource = {status: "needsAction", completed: null, notes: "sample notes"}; // If you want to change status and notes, please use this.
Tasks.Tasks.patch(resource, taskListId, taskId);
```

#### Get and update notes

In this sample script, the task IDs and notes of all tasks in a task list are retrieved, and the status and notes of all tasks are modified. When you use this, please set `taskListId`.

```
var taskListId = "### task list ID ###";
var items = Tasks.Tasks.list(taskListId).items;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var id = items[i].id;

  Logger.log("taskId: %s, notes: %s", items[i].id, items[i].notes); // Log

  var resource = {status: "needsAction",completed: null, notes:"sample notes"};
  Tasks.Tasks.patch(resource, taskListId, id);
}
```

#### References:

- [Tasks: list](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list)
- [Tasks: patch](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/patch)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. At that time, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Turns out my original code works fine the problem was with the date. Have to use the Google API date format

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
function taskNote(taskListID, taskID) {
  var task = Tasks.Tasks.get(taskListID, taskID);
  Logger.log(task.notes);
  var resource = {notes: 'Patched notes'};
  Tasks.Tasks.patch(resource, taskListID, taskID);
}
```

According to the [reference](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/patch), we should supply only relevant portions of a Tasks resource to be patched.